# TFS Build error on Coded UI Test

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfsbuild, coded-ui-tests, tfs-2015

I have a newly created coded UI test project that I checked into TFS.  When it tries to build it fails and I have these two errors:

```
The type or namespace name 'UITesting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

and

```
The type or namespace name 'Extension' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I have followed some of the other advice I've seen to no avail.  I've created a folder in the project and copied the UI test assemblies there and changed the reference, I set Copy Local to true, and I verified that these new assemblies were checked in and on the server... but I still am getting the same exact errors.

I'm out of ideas, thoughts?

**UPDATE**
I received remote access to the server;  I opened a copy of VS 2015 and compiled, ran into the same errors.  It is missing references to the coded ui dlls, so I re-added and compiled successfully.  I then saved the project but as soon as someone checks in new code to TFS, the references are gone again.

So now I don't understand why the references are there in my local environment, but are removed when checked in.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Where is the build being done? Does that computer have a Visual Studio that supports Coded UI installed, or does it have the DLLs required? You might find some of the Q&As here about running Coded UI from a console or standalone application relevant.

Comment: The build is being done on a TFS 2015 server that has a copy of VS 2015 on it.  Based on that I thought it would have the dlls but I was getting the missing reference errors so I copied them to a folder inside the project to guarantee they would be found, no luck however.

Comment: Which VS2015? Is it one that supports Coded UI?

Comment: It's the enterprise version.

Comment: See if this helps! https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2373b3ee-da10-4f4e-9e7a-995ae820c4c3/build-agent-problems-missing-assembly-references?forum=tfsbuild

Comment: I've tried that with no success.  I left the dll names I copied to the project folder the same, could this cause I conflict?  Maybe I should rename them just to be sure.

Comment: How's the result when you run the project locally?

Comment: What do you mean copy of VS 2015? Is it installed via exe/msi file or just copy VS 2015 folder from another machine? Could you open that Coded UI Test project in VS 2015 on your TFS 2015 server and run?

Comment: It compiles and runs fine locally, just when TFS tries to compile I see the errors.  And by copy I meant it has it's own installation of VS 2015 installed.

Comment: Does locally mean on TFS build agent? If not, try it on TFS build agent machine. What're detail build steps of your build definition?

Comment: The build steps are: Visual Studio Build | Visual Studio Test | Index Sources & Publish Symbols | Copy Files | Publish Build Artifacts

Comment: Does locally mean on TFS build agent?

Comment: No, it means on my laptop, not on the server.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Also, it does not compile on the server (same errors).  The references for the Coded UI stuff is missing (as in not listed, not "could not find").  I can't add them manually on the server, it says access denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I finally discovered that for some reason the reference paths were pointing to an incorrect drive on TFS.  I have no idea why but once I changed the drive, it compiles and builds successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have added the following references to your project:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting
```

Comment: The references are there, the project compiles and runs locally just fine.

Comment: @Omni, try to build your project that TFS has got on your build agent machine, and check the result.

Comment: it does not compile on the server (same errors). The references for the Coded UI dlls are missing (as in not listed, not "could not find"). I can't add them manually on the server, it says access denied.